# how to make a key start to print immediately after i start holding c++

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I am creating a kind of racing game, I have the arrow keys to move the car left and right (the up and down arrows do nothing). but when you hold left/right it takes about half a second to start going over.

here is further explanation:

so lets imagine this is my car:

```
 O
OOO  
 O 
OOO
```

and when you press <- left or -> right it moves over like it should (I have it set so it moves one space over). but when you hold it, it takes about half a second to start repeatedly moving over.

how do I make it move over immediately?

one more thing, I don't want to change the personal settings on ones computer if its possible.

thanks for answers in future.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. This is something that's handled by your operating system. Consult your operating system's technical documentation for more information on this topic. You will need to use the appropriate APIs from your operating system to read raw keyboard state, and receive raw key presses/releases, then execute the appropriate action as often as you want, according to the logic in your application. There is no turn-key solution for this, this will require some amount of development work.

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) or [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) (but more likely `GetKeyState`).

Either one lets you read the state of a key, so you'll call it once to see if the left arrow key is pressed, and then separately to see if the right arrow key is pressed (and if both are pressed...well, it's up to you to decide what to do in that case).

It's also up to you to decide how often to sample the current keyboard state, and how fast to react when the user holds down the key. Chances are pretty good that if you sample it as fast as possible, the car will react far too fast to control it well.

Comment: yes, the getkeystate worked very well. but how do I change the time to react when the user holds?

Comment: @flyguycolby: It tells you the state of the key when you call the function, so if the user holds the key down, each time you call the function, it'll show the key is still down, and you react to that appropriately.